How to model a "in-a" relationship in the object oriented programming paradigm?
I am new to object oriented programming (been programming in imperative/data-oriented style), so please bear with me. As far as I understand, inheritance models the IS-A relationship, and member variables models a HAS-A relationship. But I have a case of something like "IN-A" relationship and I am lost how this can be done in OOP style. Allow me to explain with this example.
I have a class called World that contains various things could be cars, trees, tables, whatever. I also have a class Camera. I can model it as World HAS-A Camera. But when I call Camera().render() function to render the world, it won't work because Camera doesn't have access to World's members. Now I can model Camera HAS-A World. But then World won't be able to place/move/rotate the Camera in the World because it has not access to Camera's transformation matrices.
And neither World IS-A Camera nor Camera IS-A World. Both the classes reference each other and I have no idea how this circular reference and unclear ownership can be modeled with OOP. Please help. Thank you.

A Camera is an object that operates on a World.  I would assume a single Camera could work on different Worlds, so It probably doesn't need to OWN a World, it just needs to have one passed in to it.  Right?

@TimRoberts it's the other way around. there is only one world, but there can be multiple cameras. and I want to render with cam1.render(), cam2.render() and each produces different images.

To be frank, I find the overall is-a, has-a, etc. verbiage less than helpful, unless you find yourself in an (academic?) setting where you're required to make things more complicated than they have to be. In most practical programming languages, these relationships are quite obvious. If you have a class field, of course the class 'has' that member, etc.
Not every relation has to be has-a or is-a. For the example given, isn't the most natural way to model that interaction as method call? Something like
camera.Render(world);

or
world.RenderUsing(camera);

Some people also refer to such method calls as objects 'passing messages' to other objects.
The point, however, is that world doesn't contain camera, and neither does camera contain world.

the camera has a position and pointing-direction with respect to the world. so the camera cannot exist separate from the world. so, camera.render(world) assumes that the world is a separate thing being passed to it. but camera should already know what world it is in. that is, camera has a camera.world variable. but then world won't have access to camera's transformation matrices to place it properly in the scene. I'm not sure if I'm making it clear.

@sigsegv Well, if you can place the camera in the world, then it sounds like the world contains the camera. Could you place more than one camera in the world? That would strengthen the argument for the world containing the cameras. If so, most languages will enable you to define bi-directional coupling between the two, but I'd generally consider that bad design. If you need to place the camera in the world, but you only need the camera to know about the world in order to render, it sounds like you could still pass it as an argument: From within the world: camera1.Render(this);

Like I've mentioned in the comment to original question, yes the world can have multiple cameras. Please modify the answer so that I can accept it.

I would suggest you look at possible relations and their semantics in UML. Probably, what you mean by "in-a" is "has-a" (aggregation).

Moving from procedural programming to object-oriented programming has a number of cognitive difficulties, in this case you need to start by thinking about behavior (interfaces), and only then think about implementations (classes) and their relationships.

I would suggest you the following object-oriented design for your task:

With this approach, the Camera is just a Thing on the Scene (world), which has exactly the same functional responsibility as other Things, and the Image is made by the Scene itself.

P.S. I recommend you familiarize yourself with the principle - Information Expert, it will help you to do more object-oriented design.
